# Can't install gems with bundler

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler, rbenv

I can't install gems with bundler, it always fail with a `Can't find <inser-gem-name-here> in any of the sources` message although I do have rubygems defined as a source in my gemfile.

Also, I can normally install gems with `gem install <gem-name>`, I used to install the ones that fail manually and then run bundle install so that it sees them as already installed, but that doesn't wrok anymore.

I used to use rvm, got tired of this issue (and thought it caused it) so I switched to rbenv to no avail. I'm running 1.9.2-p290.

I'm running Mac OS Lion. Thanks!

gem env output:

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.10
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.2 (2011-07-09 patchlevel 290) [x86_64-darwin11.2.0]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/X/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /Users/X/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/X/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-darwin-11
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Users/X/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
     - /Users/X/.gem/ruby/1.9.1
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
     - :sources => ["http://gems.github.com", "http://rubygems.org", "http://gemcutter.org"]
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://gems.github.com
     - http://rubygems.org
     - http://gemcutter.org
```

Also

```
$which gem
/Users/X/.rbenv/shims/gem
```

And

```
$ which ruby
/Users/X/.rbenv/shims/ruby
```

Comment: could you perhaps add your `Gemfile` and check if you have a `~/.bundle/config`

Comment: My Gemfile is fairly large, it works for other developers too, I'm in a team of 7 developer, and I'm the only one having the issues. and No, I don't have a ~/.bundle/config, and if you mean "~/.bundler", I don't have that too.

Comment: I should probably mention that $GEM_HOME doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, that I managed to resolve by exporting my http_proxy

> export http_proxy=http://user:password@host:port

Hope this helps.